# NaN Javascript Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, nan

I'm getting a response with some values from the database but when I'm going to count the total using some of these values it outputs "NaN" please tell me how can I fix this problem. thanks

```
    $.ajax({
        url:"{{ route('autocomplete.purchasetable') }}",
        method:"POST",
        data:{query:material, _token:_token},
        success:function(data){
        //console.log(data);
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        console.log(value.id, value.unit_price);
        var matid = value.id;
        var unitprice = value.unit_price;
        var cost = unitprice * quantity;
        var tr = '<tr><td></td><td>'+matid+'</td> <td name="name"><input type="text" name="materialName" value="'+material+'"></td> <td name="sex"><input type="text" name="materialID" value="'+quantity+'"></td> <td name="tel"><input type="text" name="materialID" value="'+unitprice+'"></td> <td><input type="text" name="cost" value="'+cost.toFixed(2)+'"></td><td> <button type="button" name="add" id="delete-btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-rounded btn-danger delete-btn"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td></tr>';
        $('#item_table').append(tr);
        var total = total + unitprice * quantity;
        alert(total);


});
}
});
```

Comment: perhaps there are some numbers as `strings` in your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of total would be undefined always. Since you are trying to use undefined into mathematical operations, you will indeed get NaN as the result. The solution would be to declare `var total` outside of the for loop within the ajax callback. And initialize it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

NaN means "Not A Number". Somewhere you are trying to use a value as a number, where javascript does not recognize it as a number. You could try parsing it as number with parseInt(), although it might be better to ensure that the values you are trying to use acctually are numeric.

It would be helpful to see what the ajax query gets from the server, so that we can see if there are indeed any values that are not numeric.